# Books on computational complexity

Tags: reference-request, computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, book-recommendation

Can anyone recommend a good book on the subjects of computability and computational complexity? What are the de facto standard texts (say, for graduate students) in this area?

I've heard a thing or two on these subjects from "CS people" back at the university. With lots of hand-waving they talked about the halting problem, about P versus NP, and so on.

What I would like to find now is an actual mathematics textbook (as opposed to programming and/or popular textbooks). With rigorous definitions and proofs. I'm no stranger to mathematical logic, including things like partial recursive functions and Godel's theorem. I suspect I would benefit from reading a standard graduate-level text on computational complexity. All I need now is some references to such texts. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach](http://amzn.com/0521424267) by Arora and Barak if you haven't already. I have also heard good things about Goldreich's [Computational Complexity: A Conceptual Perspective](http://amzn.com/052188473X) but I haven't read it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Carl! I've seen references to the book by Arora and Barak somewhere on the net. Now that you've given a "second opinion" - I'll definitely give it a read.

Comment: @DanShved: Glad to be of help.